# Cargar los Jtextfield con un solo Combobox

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans

tengo el siguiente formulario[image: Formulario modificar trabajador]
y necesito que al elegir el rut, dni desde el combobox  se carguen los datos de dicho trabajador desde la BD en los jtextfield (estoy trabajando desde oracle express edition 11g)
alguna idea de como hacerlo ? sería de gran ayuda por favor...

Comment: todo esto es para  poder modificar los datos de dicho trabajador....

Comment: Intenta añadir lo que haz realizado. Si buscas una opinión tu pregunta podría terminar cerrada. Te recomiendo que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

que IDE de desarrollo estás utilizando?, en mi caso uso Eclipse IDE y utilizo para diseñar en Swing, Windows Builder Editor. Para lo que tu quieres hacer debes agregar un ItemListener para que cuando cambie el valor de tu comboBoxRut puedas hacer un Select a la tabla de tu base de datos y mostrar la información en los jtextfield.

```
JComboBox comboBoxRut = new JComboBox(new Object[]{});
    comboBoxRut.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
           //En la variable arg0 se almacena el valor del Item seleccionado
           System.out.println("Combo"+ arg0.getItem());
           //haces un Select para buscar los datos a mostrar en los jtextfield
        }
    });
```

Te pregunto lo del IDE porque dependiendo de lo que utilices facilita el agregar el ItemListener. Saludos y espero que te sirva.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder, estoy utilizando Netbeans !! Entiendo tu respuesta, en este caso al ComboBox le tengo que dar el evento ItemListener y en donde imprimes ''Combo'' Agrego la consulta? Intentare con tu solución !!

Comment: Exacto, haces la consulta sql con el método de tu preferencia (hibernate, etc.).  Yo me imagino que en netbeans si haces click con botón derecho sobre el combo te da la opción de agregar el ItemListener fácilmente.